# if (memcmp (version, "\x0\x0\x0", 3) == 0 )

Tags: c

I am working on a piece of code that has a statement as below:

```
if (memcmp (version, "\x0\x0\x0", 3) == 0 )
```

What is the data that is being compared with version? Is it the same as comparing with "000"?

Comment: Side note: In this very special case, each 'x' is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not the same as `"000"`.  It is comparing three null (0) bytes.  Each byte is an actual value of zero in binary.  This is different than `"000"`, which is a string containing ASCII values for the *printable character* `0`, which is 48 (or 30 in hex.)

So `"000"` would be the same as `"\x30\x30\x30"`.

Answer (score 4):

`"\x0\x0\x0"` equals `{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }`. The fourth zero is the string null terminator.

So to answer your question - no, it's not the same as comparing with `"000"`.

`'\x0'` is hexadecimal zero, whereas `'0'` is the ASCII code of the character `0` (hexadecimal 30).

Answer (score 1):

No - it's not same as comparing against `"000"`.  It's comparing against three null characters.  An equivalent, and probably more expected, string would be `"\0\0\0"`.  Or just a 3-character array filled with `0`, for this case, where the code is only checking 3 characters anyway.

Comment: If you wanted to be tricky you could use `"\0\0"` (and `sizeof "\0\0"` for the size).

Answer (score 1):

`\x0` stands for a `char` with value 0. `0` is different, it's the ASCII character with code 0x30.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know the definition of the variable `version`.  Is it a `void *` or a `char *` or some other strange casting.  This is probably throwing up a warning during compilation.

It would also be prudent to look at how `version` is initialised just to make sure there are no errors.  It is certainly a strange way to check for (the lack of a) version number in a program.

Answer (score -1):

No.
\x0 is the literal for NULL. 
"000" is a number and have a different representation in memory.

Comment: `\x0` (or `\0`) is the literal for the NUL character. NULL (with two L's) is usually reserved for the pointer.

Comment: `"000"` is not a number - it is a string.